# Moving file from one container to other container in azure blob

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have a `azure blob` location, in that blob we have two containers one is "`container_one`" and "`container_two`".
I need to copy a file from one container to 2nd container.

Can you please help me how to achieve this functionality in `c#`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try command line tool [AzCopy](http://aka.ms/azcopy) or its library core [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement/). They can achieve blob copy in very high performance and support pausing/resuming.

Answer (score 0):

As @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft said, you can use the core data movement framework [`Azure Storage dotNet Data Movement`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/) of tool AzCopy to copy a file from one container to another.

There is a offical sample on GitHub, please refer to the function [`BlobCopySample`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/master/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Samples.cs#L115) to rewrite for satisfing your needs. The core code in the function is using the function **`TransferManager.CopyAsync`**, please refer to the [method list](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-net-data-movement/html/b9df5500-f194-0306-2de6-4a9b371afd85.htm#!) of class **`TransferManager`** to know it.